# Read file from root directory folder using filestream

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

There are two Image files in my folder which I have to call in my program. I have used:

```
AppDomain.curentDomain.baseDirectory + "Path and file name";
```

But this goes into my bin directory which I don't want; I want to read the folder from root directory where my folder name as resource I have saved my file there and call the image so please what's the code for that?

How do I read from root directory in a Windows Form Application?

Comment: AppDomain.curentDomain.baseDirectory
And
Application.startupPath
both search in the bin/debug directory of my source Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Usually, you have to set those items to be copied into the bin folder.
>   Right click in solution explorer/navigator, choose properties and set
>   "Copy to output directory". hope this will work

Answer (score 5):

Why not use the `Environment.CurrentDirectory`?

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Image1.jpg";
FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

It is a way better the combining the application startup path. :) `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returns the current path in where your Application resides.

Comment: Why not Path.Combine()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Path to File")
```

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` will give you the path that your application is being run from. It doesn't matter if it is being run within Visual Studio or whether your application is deployed.

Example Usage

```
// Read image1.jpg from application folder, into Image object
Image myImage = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "image1.jpg"));
```

Comment: I am using Windows Application so II cant use Server.MapPath 
So what is the alternative for that!! 
help dude

Comment: Why not use directly [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\YourFile.JPG")
```

returns the absolute path to your file, but this will **only** work while you're working in VS because there is no bin\Debug when you deploy your app.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\YourFile.JPG");
FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

If you plan on sending the file along with the exe, right click the file in Solution Explorer, select *Include in project*, right click again, select properties and set the *Build Action : None* and *Copy to Output Directory : Copy if newer* in the properties window, this will copy the file to your bin\Debug every time you build. Then you can use:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "YourFile.JPG");
```

which will work in VS **and** when you deploy. Better yet embed the file as a resource in your executable for a cleaner deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.MapPath("/path/to/file")`