# How to read file in windows application root directory in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filestream, windows

If i use Application.StartupPath or AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
It Search in a bin\debug folder for the file
but I have to use a folder from my root directory "Resources\imagefile.png" in ma c# .net project!

```
Filestream fs;
fs = new Filestream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "folder\\imagefile.png");
```

So how should write code to read file from my root directory in spite of using above code  or a full path of the directory that is "@C:......." and even Server.MapPath is we cant use.

> To get my application path ,but this gives something like
>   C:\Projects\XYZ\ABC\bin\Debug
>
> i don't want bin\Debug .Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Check this SO question: [Path to resource files in a VS2010 project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12212517/540352)

Comment: See this please:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236114/read-file-from-root-directory-folder-using-filestream][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236114/read-file-from-root-directory-folder-using-filestream

Comment: I just need too main application folder and I figured out just like that; string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin")) + @"\ImageName.jpg");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Using the Environment.CurrentDirectory

```
string yourpath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\YourImage.jpg";
FileStream stream = new FileStream(yourpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "YourImage.jpg")` instead.

Comment: as of VS2017 15.6 `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will return the directory of the executable.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you'd set those items to be copied into the bin folder. Right click in solution explorer/navigator, choose properties and set "Copy to output directory" to something different.

Comment: If i set that file Copy to output directory from my folder
but how should i read my root folder!
then if i will make a setup file for ma program 
then can i retrieve those file from ma program??

Comment: What do you mean by "root folder"? The folder where your .exe is?

Comment: No its where outside bin folder where i run solution